# Keep user input after press input type="submit" without using JQuery or Ajax

Tags: python, html, web

i'm creating a python web application which get multiple user input from input type="number" and calculation will be done when input type="submit" is pressed. I managed to do it but it appears that input that user entered earlier disappear because the page refresh when submitted. Can anyone help me how to keep the user input even after input type="submit" is pressed.

This is my python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import math


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='C:\\Users\\iyzadsyammil\\.PyCharmCE2017.1\\config\\fileTemplates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/Menu')
def showmenu():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/App',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def showapp():
    outpb=0
    x=0
    logpb=0
    error=" "

    if request.method=='POST':
        ingor = request.form['inGOR']
        inog = request.form['inOG']
        ingg = request.form['inGG']
        inws = request.form['inWS']
        intemp = request.form['inT']
        inpress = request.form['inP']
        innc = request.form['inNC']
        cor1 = request.form['cor1']
        cor2 = request.form['cor2']
        cor3 = request.form['cor3']
        cor4 = request.form['cor4']

        ingor = float(ingor)
        inog = float(inog)
        ingg = float(ingg)
        inws = float(inws)
        intemp = float(intemp)
        inpress = float(inpress)
        innc = float(innc)

        try:
            if cor1 == "VB":
                if inog <= 30:
                    outpb = ((27.64*ingor/ingg)*10**((-11.172*inog)/(intemp+460)))**(1/1.0937)
                else:
                    outpb = ((56.06*ingor/ingg)*10**((-10.393*inog)/(intemp+460)))**(1/1.187)
            elif cor1 == "AM":
                outpb = 0.00538088*ingor**0.715082*ingg**-1.87784*(141.5/(inog+131.5))**3.1437*(intemp+460)**1.32657
            elif cor1 == "G":
                x = (ingor/ingg)**0.816*((intemp**0.172)/(inog**0.989))
                logpb = 1.7669 + 1.7447 * math.log10(x) - (0.30218*(math.log10(x)**2))
                outpb = 10**logpb
            elif cor1 == "PF":
                x = 7.916*(10**-4)*inog**1.541-(4.561*(10**-5)*intemp**1.3911)
                outpb = ((112.727*ingor**0.577421)/(ingg**0.8439*10**x))-1391.051
            elif cor1 == "S":
                outpb = 18.2*((ingor/ingg)**0.83*10**(0.00091*intemp-0.0125*inog)-1.4)
            else:
                outpb = "Invalid Correlation!!"
        except ValueError:
            error = "Please enter an appropriate value!"

    return render_template('app.html',error=error,outpb=outpb)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my current html page :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Testing Program</title>


    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron-narrow/jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="Menu">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="App">App</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="LogIn">Log In</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="SignUp">Sign Up</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h3 class="text-muted">Experiment</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>WELCOME!!</h1>
        </div>


        <div class="row marketing">
            <form method="POST" class="col-lg-6" >
                <h3>PVT Application</h3>
                <br>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Input Data</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Solution GOR(Rs) </td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="inGOR"></td><td>scf/bbl</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Oil Gravity </td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="inOG"></td><td>API</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Gas Gravity </td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="inGG"></td><td>gr/cc</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Water Salinity </td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="inWS"></td><td>ppm</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Temperature </td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="inT"></td><td>◦F</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Pressure </td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="inP"></td><td>Psia</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Nitrogen Content </td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="inNC"></td><td>%mol</td></tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Correlation</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Bubble Point Pressure(Pb) </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="cor1">
                                <option value="none"></option>
                                <option value="VB">Vasquez and beggs</option>
                                <option value="AM">Al-Marhoun</option>
                                <option value="G">Glaso</option>
                                <option value="PF">Petrosky and Farshad</option>
                                <option value="S">Standing</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Solution GOR(Rs)</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="cor2">
                                <option value=" "></option>
                                <option value="VB">Vasquez and beggs</option>
                                <option value="AM">Al-Marhoun</option>
                                <option value="G">Glaso</option>
                                <option value="PF">Petrosky and Farshad</option>
                                <option value="S">Standing</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Oil Formation Volume Factor(Bo)  </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="cor3">
                                <option value=" "></option>
                                <option value="VB">Vasquez and beggs</option>
                                <option value="AM">Al-Marhoun</option>
                                <option value="G">Glaso</option>
                                <option value="PF">Petrosky and Farshad</option>
                                <option value="S">Standing</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Viscosity(µo) </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="cor4">
                                <option value=" "></option>
                                <option value="CC">Chew Connally</option>
                                <option value="BR">Beggs Robinson</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <table >
                    <tr><td>Result</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Pb</td><td>{{outpb}}</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Rs(Solution GOR)</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Corrected Pb(Nitrogen Effect)</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Bo</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Co</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>µo</td><td></td></tr>
                </table>
                <!--
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Enter Length (cm) : {{l}}</td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="l"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Enter Width (cm)  : {{w}}</td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="w"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Enter Height (cm) : {{h}}</td><td><input type="number" step="any" name="h"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></td></tr>
                </table>

            
                <br/>

            </form>

        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <p>Copyright © Invigour Energy 2016</p>
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery, no Ajax. but obviously you need some JS.

```
<input id="number" type="number" value="num">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">

document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var val = document.getElementById("number").value
  sessionStorage.setItem("number", val);
});

window.onload = function() {
  var session_value = sessionStorage.getItem("number") || 0;
  document.getElementById("number").value = session_value;
}
```

If you give some clues that how do you use python (db interaction, templating etc.) another solutions might be considered.

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 0):

The `<input type="submit">` will reach the `action` attribute of your `<form>` when clicked, or will refresh the page if the `action` is empty.
You can use a `<button>` element and assign it a `function` on the `click` event, for example:

```
<!-- There is no form needed if you don't need to submit -->
<div id="form">
    <input type="number" id="myNumber">
    <input type="number" id="myOtherNumber">
    <button type="button" id="submit">Calculation</button>
</div>
```

JS part:

```
window.onload = function () {
    /* get elements */
    var num_1 = document.getElementById('myNumber'),
        num_2 = document.getElementById('myOtherNumber'),
        btn = document.getElementById('submit');

    /* do what you want with your number
       when the button is clicked */
    btn.onclick = function () {
        window.console.log(num_1.value + num_2.value);
    };
};
```

Comment: But , how do i connect between JS and python script ? so far i havent be able to do that because it's like the button doesnt even connect with the JS

Comment: @iyzad unfortunately I don't know Python (I'd like to) and don't know how you can get form value with it... All I can say is that JavaScript is Front-End and lets you act on the page without refreshing. Not sure Python does the same.